# Difference between `git checkout -- foo.txt` and `git checkout foo.txt`

Tags: git, git-checkout

Normally I use `git checkout -- foo.txt` to reset a specific file in my worktree.
Today I accidentally used `git checkout foo.txt` (without `--`) and it seems it did the same.

```
$ git checkout -- foo.txt  # no output
$ git checkout foo.txt
Updated 1 path from the index
```

So I am wondering, what is the difference between the two? Or, is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
# checkout the branch foo.txt if this branch exist, otherwise the file
$ git checkout foo.txt

# checkout the file foo.txt
$ git checkout -- foo.txt
```

So if you need `--` it is for *files*, without the two characters, it is meaning for branches. If Git can't find a branch, then it will look for a file and checkout this file.

Look at official Git doku about [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

Comment: Interesting! That makes sense, thank you!