# Accidentally omitted "--" when running git checkout

Tags: git, git-checkout

Usually when I have files which have been modified, but which I do not want to include in the commit I do this:

```
git checkout -- unwanted.file
```

Today I accidentally did this to three files (I omitted the "--"):

```
git checkout unwanted.file
```

And the response was:

> Updated 3 paths from the index

I believe I reverted the changes on these 3 files which is fine, correct me if I am wrong.

But the message confuses me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`git checkout -- foo.txt\` and \`git checkout foo.txt\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66629409/difference-between-git-checkout-foo-txt-and-git-checkout-foo-txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `git checkout` (and any Unix-style command really), the `--` serves to disambiguate and splits the "normal arguments" from e.g. lists of files.

If you had a branch named `unwanted.file`, git would complain about ambiguity which you could solve by separating the filenames from the rest of the command with `--`.

So in this case, yes, these commands do the exact same thing.

Note that if you "have files which have been modified, but which I do not want to include in the commit", you can just not `git add` them. I assume you're resorting to always doing `git commit -a` or something, because by default, modifications are not staged automatically by git.

Comment: It may also be, that the files are already added, in which case another ways are to either specify explicit paths in `git commit` (only commit the files you want), or `git reset`ting the files you don't like in the commit. I strongly prefer to use the commit with explicit names. The benefit is that I don't make irreversible changes before the commit, reducing the risk of some slip-up (e.g. overwriting wrong file with the checkout).

Comment: I actually highly recommend using some GUI tool to craft your commits, allowing you to select what changes (line by line) you want, and which ones you want to discard.

Comment: *If you had a branch named `unwanted.file`, git would complain about ambiguity* ... well, Git 2.23 or later would; earlier versions of Git produce surprises, which is why the `--` is wise. :-)